# vector<int>::size_type in C++

Tags: c++, vector, size-type

What is meant by this C++ statement?

```
vector<int>::size_type x;
```

And, what is the use of the scope operator `::` here? In other words, how do we read this statement in English?

For example, for `X::x(){...}`, we say that `x()` is a `member function` of `class X`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`size_type` is a *(static) member type* of the type `vector<int>`. Usually, it is a `typedef` for `std::size_t`, which itself is usually a `typedef` for `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`.

Comment: What are the exceptions to this 'usually'? I.e., when it is unusual?

Comment: "Usually" means that the standard doesn't specify it, but that's what the popular implementations chose to do. Actually, I know an "exception". Linux glibc uses `unsigned long` for `size_t` on x86_64 platform.

Answer (score 34):

I would read it as "declare x as a variable of a type suitable for holding the size of a vector". The vector defines its own type for its length, and it's always cleanest to use that if possible, rather than "guessing" and using `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long` or `size_t` etc directly as you'd otherwise need to do.

Comment: Is it necessary to include this part `vector<int>`? How can we define `x` as the `size_type` the vector defines for itself? Thanks

Comment: @user588855: Yes, the full name must be used. It's possible that vector<int> is a specialized template, whose size_type is different from e.g. vector<std::string>::size_type.

Comment: In the case of `vector<std::string>::size_type`, wouldn't the size be an `int`? when you say that the `size_type` may be different in this case, what do you mean by that? Thanks

Comment: When you say `declare x as a variable of a type suitable for holding the size of a vector`, can we say `of a type suitable for holding the size of the largest object in the C++ application`? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

vector is a template

so the `vector` type templated with `int` has a member `typedef` called `size_type`. `x` is defined as a variable of that type.

Answer (score 2):

> Different implementations use different types to represent sizes, so
> we cannot write the appropriate type directly and remain
> implementation-independent. For that reason, it is good programming
> practice to use the size_type that the library defines to represent
> container sizes.

- Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara E. Moo