# When should I use vector<int>::size_type instead of size_t?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, int, size-t

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t) I see following:

```
for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix ! = ivec.size(); ++ix) {
    ivec[ix] = 0;
}
```

I understand that why `int` is not used here, but why not just use `size_t`?

Under what circumstances I should use `vector<int>::size_type` instead of `size_t`?

Comment: When you're iterating through a vector. (In this case.)

Comment: and when you want to be pedantic

Comment: It's more explicit. Not everyone knows they're really the same.

Comment: Don't roll your own loops if you can avoid it. The right thing here would be to write std::fill(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 0);

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The primary time to use `size_type` is in a template. Although `std::vector<T>::size_type` is usually `size_t`, `some_other_container<T>::size_type` might be some other type instead<sup>1</sup>. One of the few things a user is allowed to add to the `std` namespace is a specialization of an existing template for some user defined type. Therefore, `std::vector<T>::size_type` for some oddball `T` *could* actually be some type other than `size_t`, even though the base template defined in the standard library probably always uses `size_t`.

Therefore, if you want to use the correct type for a specific container inside a template that works with that container, you want to use `container::size_type` instead of just assuming `size_t`.

Note, however, that generic code should rarely work directly with a container. Instead, it should typically work with iterators, so instead of `container<T>::size_type`, it would typically use something like `std::iterator_traits<WhateverIterator>::difference_type` instead.

---

1. And for some specific `T`, `vector<T>::size_type` might be a different type as well--one of the few things you're allowed to put into the `std` namespace is a specialization of an existing class for a user-defined type, so for some `T`, `vector<T>` could use a completely different container than for most other types. This is typical for `vector<bool>`, but possible for other types as well.

Comment: what are some examples of widely-used containers where size_type was _not_ size_t?

Answer (score 9):

One reason to use it is consistency. While it is true that `size_t` is sufficient to index/count a `std::vector`, it conceptually insufficient to index/count a `std::list` or any other non-array based container. So, when working with containers, you should typically use `container_type::size_type`.

In generic code, when the actual type of the container is not known, you have no choice but to use `container_type::size_type`. And even in specific code, when the container is known to be a `std::vector`, there's no need to make an exception and suddenly switch to `size_t`.

Comment: *"it conceptually insufficient to index/count a std::list or any other non-array based container"*. Interesting, but I would like to know the why? What is the reason?

Comment: @Nawaz: `size_t` can accomodate the size of the largest possible continous object. This is why it is always sufficient for an array. However, there's no guarantee that `size_t` is large enough to accomodate the size of the whole available memory. If the contaner is not requred to be continous, it can potentially contain more small elements than `size_t` can count. A classic example would be old segmented memory platforms, like DOS or Win16. Their `size_t` in standard memory model was only 16 bits wide, while the available memory space was much greater than 64K.

Comment: On a segmented platform with such memory model you can't have an array larger than 64K, but you can easily have a list with more than 64K elements. Integer type that shold be large enough to count anything is  actually `uintptr_t`, not `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I'm going to dig the spec to find a statement which supports this statement *"size_t can accomodate the size of the largest possible continous object"* (if you remember the section, you could help me finding it). :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: It is not a direct quite from the standard. I'd say that simply immediately follows from the fact that `size_t` is the type that holds the result of `sizeof`.

Comment: Then I don't understand how did you draw your conclusion from that? Also, can an object be so large that it occupies the whole available memory?

Comment: @Nawaz: That is exactly how I draw that conclusion. The language does not guarantee that you can declare an object that is as large as the entire memory. (Again, in standard DOS memory model one was not allowed to declare an array or struct larger than 64K, while the total amount of memory was much greater than 64K). Any modern 64 bit implementation is free to restrict object size by, say, 4G and use 32 bit `size_t`. Such implementation can still be conforming.

Comment: Platforms with segmented memory model still exist today. AFAIK, some IBM mainframes use 128 bit memory split into 64 bit segments, with max object size limited at 64 bit boundary. `size_t` is a 64 bit type, but you can create a list with more than `2^64` elements.

Answer (score 2):

From: [vector<int>::size_type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type)

"`size_type` is a (static) member type of the type `vector<int>`. Usually, it is a `typedef` for `std::size_t`, which itself is usually a typedef for `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long`."

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, since this just means that usually they are the same. When is usually? When do I have to care about preferring one over the other?

Answer (score -2):

i think they are same.

```
typedef typename Allocator::size_type size_type;
```

Comment: "Your fallacy is anecdotal evidence"