# What is difference of using vector<int>::size_type and a normal integer?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am beginner to c++ stl language.
i want to know the difference between these two codes .
i asked my friend, but he is saying that both are same. can any one explain is these two are same or not. and explain why these are different

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<double> student_marks(20);
    for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        cout << "Enter marks for student #" << i+1
             << ": " << flush;
        cin >> student_marks[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and

```html
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<double> student_marks(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter marks for student #" << i+1
             << ": " << flush;
        cin >> student_marks[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you turn the warnings up on your compiler you'll see the difference.

Comment: `size_type` are typically unsigned, not signed like an `int`. Other than that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258126/288875

Comment: In this case they are the same but what if you changed your code to go up to `3000000000` instead of `20` ? It's good to get into habits that don't break so easily when you scale them.

Answer (score 6):

[`vector<T>::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is an implementation dependent type, which is usually `size_t`. Since it isn't specified by the standard and could potentially change, you should prefer to use it when you are dealing with elements of that type. For example, the type of `vector<T>::size()` returns a `vector<T>::size_type`. Thus, if you are iterating over the `vector` with an integral index, you would want this index to be of type `vector<T>::size_type`. This will ensure that your code is easy to maintain - if you decide to use a different implementation of the standard library, your code will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

`size_type` is one of the common typedefs that containers define.
As it happens, sizes in STL are usually of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned integral type capable of storing the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type.

The value is most likely compatible with an int, but the CORRECT thing to do is to always use `size_type`for vector indexing. That is guaranteed to ALWAYS work (Of course the index should not be greater than vector.size()).
And if you are trying to compare unsigned and signed typed (Such as your int above), you may get unpredictable results, as signed types are converted to unsigned types.