# Why declare a array of double for store a integer (c++)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm reading the accelerated c++ book and i don' t understand these statements.

```
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = homework.size();
```

homework is a array of doubles but the function size() return a integer.

So my question is : why declare a array of doubles for store a integer.

Comment: size() doesn't return the contents of the vector, it returns the number of entries in the vector - you can't have a non-integer number of entries, even if the entries themselves are doubles

Comment: No array of `double` was created . `vector<double>::size_type` is an integral type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/vectorintsize-type-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258067/when-should-i-use-vectorintsize-type-instead-of-size-t . `vec_sz` is a type suitable for holding the size of a vector of doubles.

Comment: Also, to answer part of your original question - "vec_sz" is a typedef, not a variable.  How (or if) you use it need have nothing to do with .size(), "vector" or "vector<double>".  Usually, vector::size_type is a typedef for std::size_t.  Which itself is usually a typedef for unsigned int or unsigned long long.  So you might just as easily have said "typedef unsigned int vec_sz" instead...

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why declare a array of double for store a integer?

A: There's no "array" here - it's a "vector"

A: vector::size() returns the #/items in the vector.  Size is an integer.  Each item in the vector is whatever you declared it to be (here, a double).

Comment: "There's no "array" here - it's a "vector"" ... and there is no vector either. just a type alias of an integral type and a variable called `size` declared as such.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the question shows code `homework.size()`, combined with the desire to store the result in a `vector<double>::size_type` that strongly implies `homework` is a `vector` object.