# C++: Access violation

Tags: c++, for-loop, matrix, access-violation

I am creating a matrix, then I want to fill its values with 0.

I am getting an access violation error in this line:

```
mat1[x][y]=0;
```

But I don't see why.

This is my code:

```
vector<float>getJenksBreaks(vector<float>uFloats,const unsigned int uNumClass)
{

    float* first(&uFloats[0]);
    float* last(first + uFloats.size());
    std::sort(first, last);

    float **mat1 = new float*[uFloats.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < uFloats.size(); ++i) 
    {
        mat1[i] = new float[uNumClass+1];
    }
    for (unsigned long x=0;x<uNumClass+1;x++)
    {
        for (unsigned long y=0;y<uFloats.size();y++)
        {
            mat1[x][y]=0;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody see my error?

Thank you.

Comment: You're using `mat[x][y]` instead of `mat[y][x]`?

Comment: Not a solution but an observation:  You should strongly consider using vector<float>::iterator rather then float * for first and last, and using ufloats.begin() and uFloats.end() to find the beginning and end of the vector.

Comment: Oh, it seems you are right. Can you make your comment the reply?

Comment: Is there some reason you are dealing with `vectors` as inputs and return values, yet feel the need to manage memory dynamically instead of using `vector`s internal to your function?

Comment: @ZacHowland I don't know what you mean. I see no other way than using "new" to dynamically create a matrix whose size is not known at compilation time.

Comment: @tmighty `std::vector`.  Specifically, `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`, which will properly handle all the memory allocations and deallocations for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing with dynamic memory manually:

```
vector<float> getJenksBreaks(vector<float> uFloats, const unsigned int uNumClass)
{
    std::sort(uFloats.begin(), uFloats.end());

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> mat(uFloats.size());
    std::for_each(mat.begin(), mat.end() [&](std::vector<float>& v)
    {
        v.resize(uNumClass);
    });

    // ...
}
```

Or (even better) ...

```
vector<float> getJenksBreaks(vector<float> uFloats, const unsigned int uNumClass)
{
    std::sort(uFloats.begin(), uFloats.end());

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> mat(uFloats.size(), std::vector<float>(uNumClass));

    // ...
}
```

Which will do exactly what you did without the need to worry about proper placement of your indexes, and is much less prone to errors.

Finally, you can simply create a simple Matrix wrapper class:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : _matrix(rows, std::vector<float>(cols))
    {

    }

    // other matrix functions

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> _matrix;
};
```

Which would then turn your code into

```
vector<float> getJenksBreaks(vector<float> uFloats, const unsigned int uNumClass)
{
    std::sort(uFloats.begin(), uFloats.end());
    Matrix matrix(uFloats.size(), uNumClass);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The foreach and lambda are not required: `std::vector<std::vector<float>> mat(uFloats.size(), std::vector<float>(uNumClass));` (At this point you want a little `Matrix` wrapper class)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True.  I'll add that as an even simpler alternate solution.

Comment: @ZacHowland Can you tell me how to access the matrix in a good way? I wanted to use  for (unsigned long y=0;y<uFloats.size();y++)
 {
  for (unsigned long x=0;x<uNumClass+1;x++)
  {
   mat1._matrix[y][x]=0;
  }
 } However, this does not work, and I guess 10 people will immediately yell at me "Don't do it like this!!", even if it worked. Or in other words: Would it be possible to update your code so that it is possible to set and get values? That would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : _matrix(rows, std::vector<float>(cols))
    {
  for (unsigned long r=0;r<rows+1;r++)
  {
   vector <float>nRow;
   nRow.resize(cols+1);
   _matrix.push_back(nRow);
  }
    } Is this correct?

Comment: @tmighty:  No.  There is no need for the loop as the initialization list will do it all for you.  If you want the matrix to be 1 row and 1 column bigger than the input, you would do `Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : _matrix(rows + 1, std::vector<float>(cols + 1)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Change these loops

```
for (unsigned long x=0;x<uNumClass+1;x++)
{
    for (unsigned long y=0;y<uFloats.size();y++)
    {
        mat1[x][y]=0;
    }
}
```

to

```
for (unsigned long x=0;x<uFloats.size();x++)
{
    for (unsigned long y=0;y<uNumClass+1;y++)
    {
        mat1[x][y]=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i would also add, use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long` for the first loop

Comment: @lolando, It would be a serious mistake. The correct type is std::vector<float>::size_type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow since you are not operating on the vector anymore, there would be no difference in using `size_t` vs `vector<>::size_type`.  It would not be a "serious mistake"; the serious mistake is using dynamic memory allocations manually instead of using `vectors` ...

Comment: @Zac Howland You are wrong because you are operating with member function size()

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That is simply because of the poor code before it.  Since `size_type` is a typedef for `size_t`, it is not going to matter:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/c-vectorintsize-type (IIRC, the standard actually defines that `size_type` must be typedef'd to `size_t` - I'll have to check when I can get to the standard).