# How could a variable with a type of string::size_t be initialized to zero

Tags: c++, string, size

```
string s("Hello World!!!");// punct_cnt has the same type that s.size returns;  <br>
decltype(s.size()) punct_cnt = 0;// count the number of punctuation characters in s  <br>for (auto c : s) // for every char in s
if (ispunct(c)) // if the character is punctuation  <br>
++punct_cnt; // increment the punctuation counter  <br>
cout << punct_cnt<< " punctuation characters in " << s << endl;
```

This is the code example on C++ primer 5th.  
 Could someone explain to me why could it assign 0 to initialize a variable with a type of string::size_t which is not an integer type?  
 I couldn't find the similar question on Q&A. Thanks!

Comment: Who tell you that `std::string::size_type` is not an integer type?

Comment: size_type => http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849646/1746118

Comment: @ForEveR I think I have seen something like string:: size_type is not int because int can only hold 32 bits but string::size_t can guarantee to hold enough number.

Comment: @Des1gnWizard Theres a big difference between "not an `int`" and not an integer type. `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` are all integer/integral types, only one of them is `int` though. Also the size of `int` is not set in stone, [see the table on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), width in bits: *at least 16*

Comment: @ForEveR Oh,,,Yeah I actually want to say not an "int" but anyway both wrong. Thanks for pointing out this!

Comment: @Borgleader - `byte` is not a standard type in C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker My bad I meant char, but by the time i realized it i couldnt edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decltype(s.size())`
Return a type, in this case an size_t (unsigned int).

See : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/

Comment: Oh..Thanks for pointing out.. I have been learning C++ for several whole days and probably mixed some concepts

Answer (score 3):

`size_t` is actually an integer type
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t