# vector size - 1 when size is 0 in C++

Tags: c++, vector, size

The following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> value;
    cout << value.size() << endl;  // output 0
    cout << value.size() - 1 << endl;  // output 18446744073709551615
}
```

Why the second output is not -1? What happens at the second cout?

Comment: Simple: Overflow (underflow)...

Comment: Because it is an unsigned value. Google food for you: 2's complement.

Comment: There are no  2's complement concerns here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`vector::size()` is of type `size_t` which is an unsigned type, and unsigned integers can't represent negative numbers.

Comment: Link to related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/vectorintsize-type-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Unsigned integer types in C++ do “wrap around arithmetic” a.k.a. clock arithmetic a.k.a. modulo arithmetic. And the result of any standard library `size` function is unsigned, usually the type `size_t`. And so, when you subtract 1 from 0 of type `size_t`, you get the largest `size_t` value.

To avoid these problems you can include `<stddef.h>` and define

```
using Size = ptrdiff_t;
```

and further (the second function here requires inclusion of `<bitset`),

```
template< class Type >
auto n_items( Type const& o )
    -> Size
{ return o.size(); }

template< Size n >
auto n_items( std::bitset<n> const& o )
    -> Size
{ return o.count(); }       // Corresponds to std::set<int>::size()
```

Then you can write

```
n_items( v )
```

and get a signed integer result, and `-1` when you subtract 1 from 0.

Answer (score 1):

value.size() returns an unsigned type, so by doing -1 you are actually doing an overflow

Answer (score 1):

The output is automatically casted to `size_t` because that's the return type of `value.size()`, which is an `unsigned` type. Hence you see an `unsigned` value printed.

Answer (score 1):

The `.size()` returns a `size_t` type that is an `unsigned int`. The second output is the maximum integer of your machine.