# Sorting a vector in descending order and adding from the front works, but sorting in ascending order and adding from the back doesn't?

Tags: c++, sorting, overflow

I'm attempting a problem on codeforces. The gist of the question: There are `n` days, and on each day there are `k` products up for sale and `l` customers visiting. Each customer will either purchase one product or if there aren't any left, leave without buying anything. Any excess unpurchased product is thrown away. In order to maximise the number of products sold, you choose any `f` days from `n` and double the number of products put up for sale. Find the maximal number of products you can sell.

So my approach was to calculate `min(2k, l) - min(k, l)` for each of the days and store it in a vector `v`. I sort this vector and sum up the largest f of these values. Then, I sum up `min(k, l)` for every single day, and adding it to the previous sum I get my answer.

The problem is: When I do `sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend())` and add the first f elements, I get the right answer. However, when I do `sort(v.begin(), v.end())` and add the elements from index `int i = v.size() - 1; i > v.size() - 1 - f; i--` aka the last f elements, I fail on  the 28th test case.

The ranges are `1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5, 0 ≤ f ≤ n` and `0 ≤ k i, l i ≤ 10^9`. I'm not sure if it's a case of overflow though I doubt it because I used long long to store my answer, and on the test case I failed the expected output is a small integer. Thanks for reading, hope someone could help me out on this

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, f;
    cin >> n >> f;
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int> v2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int k, l;
        cin >> k >> l;
        int difference = min(2*k, l) - min(k, l);
        v.push_back(difference);
        v2.push_back(min(k, l));
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    long long ans = 0;
    for(int i = v.size()-1; i > v.size()-1-f; i--)
    {
        ans += v[i];  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++)
    {
        ans += v2[i];
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vector size - 1 when size is 0 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701662/vector-size-1-when-size-is-0-in-c)

Comment: `v.size()` returns a `std::size_t`, which is unsigned. If `f == n`, `v.size()-1-f` will wrap around to a big number. Be careful when you subtract from `size()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand my mistake now xD