# Why is debugger evaluating expression to false, when it's real value is true?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop

The condition `i < (scores.size() - 1)` evaluates to `false` by the debugger (see screenshot). But the runtime evaluates it to `true`. The debugger also reports the return type from scores.size() to be `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> scores{};

    for (int i = 0; i < (scores.size() - 1); i++) {
        std::cout << "Hello?";
    }

}
```

[image]

I am aware of `size()` returning an `unsigned` (and I saw [vector size - 1 when size is 0 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701662/vector-size-1-when-size-is-0-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but why is there such a discrepancy of what the debugger shows me?

Details on my toolchain:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.5
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.7.5+30523.141
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA445
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019


Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards


Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vector size - 1 when size is 0 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701662/vector-size-1-when-size-is-0-in-c)

Comment: `std::vector::size_type` is unsigned

Comment: use `i + 1 < scores.size()` instead

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure the surprise here is just that when you subtract 1 from 0 and you're doing unsigned math (because scores.size() is unsigned) you get a max-int-sized number without any compile failure.  You have only your ever-growing experience to save you from making these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: if your question is about that discrepancy we can reopen it. I thought you just want to know why it fails and how to fix, and maybe was a bit too fast with flagging as dupe (though the question would need a bit of rewording then)

Comment: @idclev463035818 question updated to better reflect issue

Comment: made some minor edits (you dont need "UDATE" or "EDIT" in the question. that doesnt make it easier to read the question, rather the opposite. If someone cares about the edit history they can look at it. And the question was only in the title but missing in the body. And better mention the other question, to avoid it being closed again as dupe) and reopened

Comment: Debugger is messed up given "The debugger also reports the return type from scores.size() to be int."

Comment: In my opinion, Visual Studio regard unsigned type ` scores.size()-1` as `int`, but in actual compilation, it is compared with `0`and ` scores.size()-1`. This problem should be a compiler problem.  I suggest you go to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit this question.