# Is there any applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551612 to null pointer?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

LeetCode
Problem Name: 155. Min Stack

I was trying to solve this but getting runtime error everytime. Would you like to help me to solve it?

```
class MinStack {
   
public:
        vector<int> all;
        vector<int>gettingMin;
    MinStack() {
        vector<int> all;
        vector<int>gettingMin;
    }
    
    void push(int val) {
        all.push_back(val);
        int lastIndex = gettingMin.size() - 1;
        int lastMinVal = gettingMin[lastIndex];
        if(lastMinVal >= val) gettingMin.push_back(val);
        else gettingMin.push_back(lastMinVal);
    }
    
    void pop() {
        int lastIndex = gettingMin.size() - 1;
        if(lastIndex < 0) return;
        all.erase(all.begin()+lastIndex);
        gettingMin.erase(gettingMin.begin()+lastIndex);
    }
    
    int top() {
        int val = all.back();
        return val;
    }
    
    int getMin() {
        int val = gettingMin.back();
        return val;
    }
};
```

ERROR:
`Line 1041: Char 34: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551612 to null pointer (stl_vector.h) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046:34`

Runtime Error is happening, help me to understand.

Comment: The `size()` method returns an unsigned value. If that's zero and you subtract 1, the number will wrap to a very large value. If you then implicitly convert that to a (signed) integer (which might even be a smaller data type), it might wrap. Oddly, the value you're seeing here appears to be `-4` represented in an unsigned 64-bit value. You really need to show a [mre] that includes the example data and testing code if you want a definitive answer about what's really happening.

Comment: Address sanitizer should have shown the entire call stack. You only show the top of the stack here, but not the line of _your_ code that it came from. Note also that your `MinStack` constructor makes no sense. You define two local variables, overloading the class member symbols, and then don't use them for anything. This demonstrates a misunderstanding of how constructors work.

Comment: [vector size - 1 when size is 0 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701662/vector-size-1-when-size-is-0-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

at the `push()` function, I haven't check for the null vector. add the below checker and it'll resolve the issue.

```
if(gettingMin.size() == 0)
    {
        gettingMin.push_back(val);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `.empty()` instead of `.size() == 0`