# C++ size_type does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates, g++, codeblocks, return-type

While trying to create a function to calculate the length of a vector, I encountered `error: 'size_type' does not name a type` for line 2. Is `size_type` not already a type? What exactly does it mean to name a type?

```
template<class vecType>
size_type len(vector<vecType> inVector) {
    size_type vecSize = inVector.size();
    return vecSize;
}
```

FYI : Using `gcc/g++ 4.9.2`

Comment: "name" is a verb in this case. It means `size_type` is not a name of a data type. It means you have not told the compiler what `size_type` is.

Comment: `size_type` is usually attached to another class, such as `vector::size_type`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/vectorintsize-type-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at a regular function, not a function template.

```
int add_two(int in)
{
   return (in + 2);
}
```

The `int` before the name of the function is the return type. If the compiler cannot determine that it represents a type, it will report that as an error. If you had a typo and wrote

```
imt add_two(int in)
{
   return (in + 2);
}
```

the compiler will complain that `imt` is not a type.

A function template must also have a return type. You have:

```
template<class vecType>
size_type len(vector<vecType> inVector) {
    size_type vecSize = inVector.size();
    return vecSize;
}
```

Here, you have `size_type` before the function name. If the compiler cannot determine that `size_type` is indeed a type, it will complain. If `size_type` is a known type, the compiler will proceeds with that type being the return type of the function.

You can use:

```
template<class vecType>
typename std::vector<vecType>::size_type len(vector<vecType> inVector) {
   ...
}
```

to let the compiler know that `std::vector<vecType>` has a type called `size_type` and the return value of that function is that type. You will need to use `typename std::vector<vecType>::size_type` since it is a dependent type name. See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more on the subject.

Also, you have to fix the declaration of the variable `vecSize` in the function.

```
template<class vecType>
typename std::vector<vecType>::size_type len(vector<vecType> inVector) {
   typename std::vector<vecType>::size_type vecSize = inVector.size();
   return vecSize;
}
```

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can simplify the variable declaration to

```
   auto vecSize = inVector.size();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
vector<vecType>::size_type vecSize = inVector.size ();
```