# Why is size_type a 32-bit integer on a 64-bit platform?

Tags: c++

The [std::vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) member function is like this:

> void resize (size_type n);

Per my understanding, `size_type` should be a `64-bit long` type on a `64-bit` platform. But compiling the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<char> v;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    v.resize(INT_MAX +1);
    for (auto i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following warning is generated:

```
g++ -std=c++11 hello.cpp
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:11:19: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
  v.resize(INT_MAX +1);
```

So the `size_type` is still `32-bit int` even though we're working on a  `64-bit` platform?

Comment: There's no requirement for vector's `size_type`, other than it being unsigned.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849632/vectorintsize-type-in-c) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Comment: INT_MAX +1 invoked UB here.

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with `size_t` - `INT_MAX + 1` is an addition of two integer literals (which evaluates to a type of `int`), so it will overflow the type of `int`. The conversion to `size_t` happens *after* the addition

Comment: Try `v.resize(static_cast<vector<char>::size_type>(INT_MAX) + 1);`

Comment: `(size_t)INT_MAX + 1` should be enough. Hope you have that much virtual memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector's `size_type` is probably a typedef for `allocator::size_t` which is (probably) a typedef for [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is an unsigned type. The generated warning has nothing to do with the vector's `resize()` signature. You are overflowing the max integer limit and your `INT_MAX + 1` expression invokes [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Also the `for` loop deduces the type of `i` to be `int` which will also issue a warning when comparing signed and unsigned values. If you really want to you can cast to `size_type` and add `1`:

```
v.resize(static_cast<std::vector<char>::size_type>(INT_MAX) + 1);
```

and append the `u` literal to initial value inside the `for` loop:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < v.size(); i++)
```

You can get the underlying type name with:

```
std::cout << typeid(std::vector<char>::size_type).name();
```

Comment: So the most correct format should be: `for (vector<char>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )`, right?